# Error "Unsupported major.minor version" en Java

Tags: jvm, java

Al intentar ejecutar una clase hecha en [java](/questions/tagged/java), aparece el siguiente mensaje de error:

> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: MiClase (Unsupported major.minor version 50.0)

¿Qué significa este mensaje de error?

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Este error se debe a que desde la JVM (Java Virtual Machine: Máquina Virtual de Java) predeterminada de tu equipo, se intenta ejecutar una clase que fue compilada en una versión del JDK (Java Development Kit: Kit de Desarrollo Java) superior a la de la JVM (por ejemplo, intentar ejecutar con la JVM 1.4 una clase compilada en JDK 1.6).

Si deseas verificar la versión de la clase conflictiva, ejecuta el comando `javap` que es el descompilador que viene incluido en el JDK, ejecutándolo desde `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` (se recomienda hacerlo desde la versión más reciente del JDK) .

Por ejemplo, si deseas saber en qué versión de Java está compilada la clase `MiClase.class`, ejecuta los siguientes comandos:

1. `javap -verbose MiClase.class | findstr "major"` lo cual retornaría algo como:

   > major version: 50
2. `javap -verbose MiClase.class | findstr "minor"` lo cual retornaría algo como:

   > minor version: 0

Así las equivalencias entre las versiones de Java y sus 'major version' son las siguientes a la fecha:

> Java 1.2 corresponde a major version 46
>
> Java 1.3 corresponde a major version 47
>
> Java 1.4 corresponde a major version 48
>
> Java 5 corresponde a major version 49
>
> Java 6 corresponde a major version 50
>
> Java 7 corresponde a major version 51
>
> Java 8 corresponde a major version 52

([Fuente del listado](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170832/list-of-java-class-file-format-major-version-numbers))

Esta es una forma sencilla de hacer esta comprobación con el comando `javap`, aunque existen más. Si las conoces, eres bienvenido para hacer tu aporte como comentario a esta respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Estás ejecutando tu programa con una versión menor a con la que fue compilado.

Ejemplo, compilaste con 1.8 e intentas correr en la versión 1.7

Comment: Hola, me parece que esto ha debido ser un comentario