# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java

```
package excel; //Ayuda porque me tira error, intento crear un Excel

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.logging.Level;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;


public class Excel {
    public static void crearExcel()
    {
        creaRExcel();
        System.out.println("Se ha creado el Excel correctamente");
    }

    public static void creaRExcel()
    { 
        Workbook libro = new XSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet hoja = libro.createSheet("Hola Java");
        Row fila = hoja.createRow(0);
        fila.createCell(0).setCellValue("Document");
        try 
        {
            FileOutputStream archivo = new FileOutputStream("Proteccion_Productos.xlsx");
            libro.write(archivo);
            archivo.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Excel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Excel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        crearExcel();
    }

}
```

> run: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook : Unsupported major.minor version
>   52.0
>
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
>
> at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
>
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
>
> at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>
> at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>
> at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>
> at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
>
> at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2625)
>
> at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2866)
>
> at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1676)
>
> at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
>
> at
>   sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
>
> Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) , también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad. Tu pregunta es de muy baja calidad.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Error "Unsupported major.minor version" en Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/178/error-unsupported-major-minor-version-en-java)

Answer (score -1):

Version 52.0 = java 8, tal vez tengas un conflicto de jre anterior y uno mas nuevo, borra el jre mas viejo,  e instala jdk, mas reciente, que ya trae integrado jre.